# type *NewsAnswer does not support indexing when try to range over struct

Tags: go

i defined struct like below

```
type NewsAnswer struct {
    ReadLink              string           `json:"readLink"`
    QueryContext          queryContextJson `json:"queryContext"`
    TotalEstimatedMatches int              `json:"totalEstimatedMatches"`
    Sort                  []sortJson       `json:"sort"`
    Value                 []valueJson      `json:"value"`
}

type queryContextJson struct {
    OriginalQuery string `json:"originalQuery"`
    AdultIntent   bool   `json:"adultIntent"`
}

type sortJson struct {
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    ID         string `json:"id"`
    IsSelected bool   `json:"isSelected"`
    URL        string `json:"url"`
}

type valueJson struct {
    Name          string         `json:"name"`
    URL           string         `json:"url"`
    Image         imageJson      `json:"image"`
    Description   string         `json:"description"`
    Provider      []providerJson `json:"provider"`
    DatePublished string         `json:"datePublished"`
}

type imageJson struct {
    Thumbnail thumbnailJson `json:"thumbnail"`
}

type thumbnailJson struct {
    ContentUrl string `json:"thumbnail"`
    Width      int    `json:"width"`
    Height     int    `json:"height"`
}

type providerJson struct {
    Type string `json:"_type"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

I am getting JSON in API response I converting JSON to struct like below

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

ans := new(NewsAnswer)
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &ans)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}
```

now I want to loop through data  in `value` so I try to do range like below

```
for index, value := range ans["value"] {}
```

but getting this error `type *NewsAnswer does not support indexing`
what should I have to do?

Comment: Struct fields are accessed using expressions called "[selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)" e.g. `structValue.FieldName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should range over `Value` field directly.

```
for index, value := range ans.Value {}
```